# getResource causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, getresource

I know there have been multiple posts on the subject but my issue seems to be one that hasn't been brought up yet. Under no circumstance can I seem to get `getResource` to correctly return a path location. It got to the point where I try to find the current class' path and even that is giving me a null pointer exception. Here is a list of ways I have went about it.

testProject

- src
    -klass.java
- bin -klass.class
- resource
- lib

  ```
   public class Klass
   { 
          public void resourceTest()
          {   
              ClassLoader.getSystemResource(Klass.class.getSimpleName() + ".class").toString(); 
              Klass.class.getClass().getResource(Klass.class.getSimpleName() + ".class").toString();
              Klass.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(Klass.class.getSimpleName() + ".class").toString();   
          }
   }
  ```

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. I've used `getResource` before so this is driving me crazy. Thanks!

Comment: can you share your project structure?

Comment: maybe try this.getClass() etc instead of Klass.class

Comment: All of these calls are throwing the same Exception, aren't they?

Comment: Is `Klass` exactly as shown or is it in a package?

Comment: Also, `Klass.class.getClass().getResource(...)` should be `Klass.class.getResource(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Klass.class.getClass()` is equivalent to `Class.class`, since the class of `Klass.class` is `Class`. So this would be trying to load a resource in the `java.lang` package. You just want `Klass.class.getResource()`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a klass.class as last row. Try to use Klass.class with capital K